# Problems with killing jobs

Tags: linux

I would like to kill a job serial, which contains several calculations. With the command 'kill PID', where PID refers to process ID, the currently running calculation cancels, but the process has not been stopped. Instead, the next calculation starts, but I would like to kill the entire job, the entire process.

Comment: If there is a daemon watching the child processes you need to kill it. You can find the parent PID from your child process

Comment: You should clarify how the jobs are started. Is it a shell loop that starts them?

Answer (score 0):

The `kill -9 <pid>` should do the job. Unfortunately this might not always work if program is poorly programmed you might be unable to kill it.